# Weird layer suffix issue running in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: keras, jupyter

```
from keras import layers as KL
def create_model():
    inp = KL.Input(shape=(None,), name='input')
    embedding = KL.Embedding(input_dim=10, output_dim=10)(inp)
    out = KL.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='dense')(embedding)
    model = KM.Model(inputs=[inp], outputs=[out])

    return model

model1 = create_model()
model1.summary()
model2 = create_model()
model2.summary()
```

The output for model1:

```
embedding_1 (Embedding)
```

model2:

```
embedding_2 (Embedding)
```

Why the name of the layer is not fixed? If I run `create_model()` again, the name will be suffixed with `_3`.

Any idea? Does this has anything to do with running in Jupyter? Does Jupyter kernel somehow cache the variables? Thanks!

Comment: Keras does this, because layer names have to be unique.

Comment: Does Keras maintain the layer names globally? `create_model()` defines a new model every time it is called.

Comment: It creates them so they are globally unique but they don't have to. Note that this has nothing to do with variable names.

Comment: Is there a way to reset the counter? I need the layer names to be fixed because I need to port the model as tensforflow format and use it in C#. If the name of the layer is changed every time when the model is trained, I have to update the code.

Comment: Possibly of help: [Keras - All layer names should be unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43452441/keras-all-layer-names-should-be-unique)

Answer (score 0):

Each layer has a parameter called `name`, which sets the layer name. You can use this to put your own fixed names to layers, so you can operate on them later.

For example:

```
conv1 = Conv2D(..., name='conv1')(some_input)
```

Comment: This won't work. The name will be `embedding_1/embedding` or `embedding_2/embedding` after ported as Tensorflow format

Comment: @zsong I get the feeling that we have a XY problem here, because you don't explain what exactly is the problem, but you are trying to make your solution work. Please state the full problem.