# Error when trying to rename a pretrained model on tf.keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I trained two models in order to ensemble them,
when I try to load them with this code:

```
  from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
  models=[]
  modelTemp=load_model('models/full.h5')
  modelTemp.name = "inception1"
  models.append(modelTemp)
```

error occur :

```
  AttributeError: Can't set the attribute "name", likely because it conflicts with an existing read-only @property of the object. Please choose a different name.
```

full error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __setattr__(self, name, value)
   1968       try:
-> 1969         super(tracking.AutoTrackable, self).__setattr__(name, value)
   1970       except AttributeError:

AttributeError: can't set attribute

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __setattr__(self, name, value)
   1972             ('Can\'t set the attribute "{}", likely because it conflicts with '
   1973              'an existing read-only @property of the object. Please choose a '
-> 1974              'different name.').format(name))
   1975       return
   1976 

AttributeError: Can't set the attribute "name", likely because it conflicts with an existing read-only @property of the object. Please choose a different name.
```

Comment: Did you try other names?

Comment: yes I tried and it didn't work same error

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to [this question here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49550182/keras-rename-model-and-layers)
you need to use:

```
modelTemp._name = 'inception'
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. Apparently they didn't include a name setter decorator and must change the internal attribute manually

Comment: Is this the proper way?  Messing with "_name" seems dangerous.  Perhaps there is some reason tensorflow team did this.

Answer (score -1):

I have answered the same topic here [How to rename Pre-Trained model ? ValueError 'Trained Model' is not a valid scope name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63786982/how-to-rename-pre-trained-model-valueerror-trained-model-is-not-a-valid-scop)

Solution is:

```
model = load_model(r"C:\Master\Learning\Agri_Intelligence\Models\Model.h5")
model._name = "New_Model_Name"
model.save(r"C:\Master\Learning\Agri_Intelligence\Models\New_Model.h5")
```

Comment: Is your own question (that you link to here) the same as this question? If so, then it would be more appropriate to add your detailed answer here instead of posting a similar question.

Comment: @FluffyKitten Yeah, exactly!